# Responsive Website getting cut off on the right in Internet Explorer

Tags: internet-explorer, responsive-design

My clients website is being cut off in IE @ 1024x768.  I'm using a "Responsive" template and the Dev has not been very helpful with a solution.  My client's office computers all view at that resolution, and an easy fix would be to change the screen resolution for all their computers, but we all know that is just an in house fix that doesn't solve the issue of their clients viewing their site.

The website views fine in all other browsers, which reminds me why I have grown to harbor disgust for IE.

Has anyone had the same issue?  Is there a fix I can drop into the main.css file?

Website is http://zczperio.com

Please bear in mind that I'm new to css!

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I guess the main problem is that you use pixel precise values for your images.

```
<a href="http://zczperio.com" class="logo" style="width: 1024px; height: 150px;">
    <img src="http://zczperio.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/05/HeaderLogo6.png" alt="" width="1024" height="162" class="logo_def">
</a>
```

So, you should change your fixed width values into percentages and removing the height on your images like:

```
<a href="http://zczperio.com" class="logo" style="width: 100%;">
    <img src="http://zczperio.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/05/HeaderLogo6.png" alt="" class="logo_def">
</a>
```

Comment: Hmmm...  Made the change, but the entire page is getting still getting cut off.  Notice the Header_nav, the phone numbers and the sidebar...